# Test the release before uploading to the stores for mobile app

Tags: flutter, testing, continuous-integration

Have you already deployed tests on mobile (iOS, Android, with Flutter), cross version -> switch from one version to another. The classic case is the test of a version before submission. I would like to test the version switching and continuity, in an efficient and simple way (via a CI maybe). Do you have any ideas?

Thank you for your time,